# Multiple postgreSQL Installations on the same system

Tags: postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have installed two version of postgreSQL on my Windows 7 dev box. Ver. 9.1 (32-bit) and 9.2 (64-bit). During installation I assigned ver. 9.1 port 5432 and ver 9.2 port 5433. However, whenever I run basic commands like createdb.exe from the 9.2\bin directory, the command runs against the wrong port. Regardless of what commands I run, they always default to the port of the first install (5432). The install directories and data directories are in different locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a port, the Postgres tools (e.g. `psql`) default to 5432. Use the `-p` switch to change the port that the tool should use, e.g.

```
psql -p 5433 mydb myuser
```

Or for the createdb command:

```
createdb -p 5433 the_new_db
```

Please read the respective chapters in the manual for details.

If you don't want to specify the port number each time, you can set an environment variable that is picked up by the Postgres tools. This is also explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html